# How to validate if an input date is in yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ format?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format

I want to validate if an input date is in format "**yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ**". Can you please suggest how can i validate the date.

Example:  2021-04-16T02:30:00.234Z

```
def validate_date(date):
    #code which will validate the date
```

Comment: did you try anything? e.g. test against a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) pattern? or making use of [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)?

Comment: re.search("^\d\d\d\d-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(T|t)(00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]).([000-999]|0[10-99]|00|[0-9])(Z|z)$", "2021-04-16T02:30:00.234Z")

Comment: @MrFuppes I tried above pattern but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the string against a regular expression:

```
import re

def check_format(datestring, _pat=re.compile("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z")):
    # "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
    return re.match(_pat, datestring)
```

and if you want to make sure it is a *valid* date/time, parse it:

```
from datetime import datetime

def valid_date(datestring):
    if check_format(datestring):
        try:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(datestring.replace('Z', '+00:00'))
        except ValueError:
            return False # invalid date/time string
    return False # unaccepted format
```

..and test it:

```
for d in ("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",       # ok
          "2021-01-01Z00:00:00.000T",       # nok
          "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z",    # nok
          "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00"): # nok
    print(d, "->", valid_date(d))
```